# Django-debug-tolbar не показывается

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я использую django 4.0.3 и django-debug-tolbar 3.2.4. По какой-то причине панель инструментов не отображается на моем сервере. Я пробовал много способов, но ни один из них не работал у меня. Я буду очень благодарен за любую помощь

> **settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# debug_toolbar moved here.
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE += [
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    ]
    INSTALLED_APPS += [
        'debug_toolbar',
    ]
    INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1', ]

    # this is the main reason for not showing up the toolbar
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }
```

> **urls.py**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Напрашивается очевиднейший вопрос: включен ли DEBUG и где конкретно он прописан?

Comment: Debug равен True и прописан он в sittings.py